# Alert screen while server is loading in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm loading a series of spreadsheets into the server using Laravel Excel and one of them is extremely large and I'd like to know whether it's possible to show the user that the server is loading the information so that they don't close the tab and know that something is happening besides the "loading" favicon.

The spreadsheet itself isn't heavy but the processing time is long and the browser says "Waiting..." Most of the progress bars I've seen use AJAX and focus on uploading time. I wonder if there's something for Laravel and if it's necessary to use AJAX.

Laravel Excel [has this feature](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/progress-bar.html) but it's only intended for the console.

Comment: You could look into https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

Comment: I read that but didn't know how to apply it to my project in practice. Laravel Excel has a ShouldQueue concern but I don't know anything else.

Comment: Usually the heavy work is done asynchronously via ajax so if you could change your code to not need to load the spreadsheets along with the page but send them via an AJAX request you can show your own loaders from (e.g.) [here](https://loading.io/css/)

Comment: That looks so cool, thank you.